# Feature in google analytics for analyzing custom navigation sequences

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to figure out how to get reports of how many sessions followed a particular sequence of pages.  For example:

How many users went to

- /login.aspx then
- /home.aspx then
- /SomeotherPage.aspx then
- ended their session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom sequence segment:

[image]